Lag function - issue
I have data like that :



Year
Value




2022
1000


2023
500



and I want to create column with previous values like that:



Year
Value
Value_PY




2022
1000
null


2023
500
1000


2024
null
500



The LAG() function isn't the best solution for this because I get the table without 2024 row. How can I solve this?
lag(value) OVER(order by Year)

How can I solve this? What should I add to this LAG() function?

Add a row for 2024. Union with a select '2024' as Year, NULL as value. Then apply your lag column.
SELECT *, lag(value) OVER(order by Year) AS Value_PY FROM
(
SELECT * FROM example
UNION 
SELECT '2024' AS Year, NULL AS value
) t




Year
Value
Value_PY




2022
1000
null


2023
500
1000


2024
null
500



